# nodejs oracledb get data from callback

Tags: node.js, oracle, callback

i am  using **nodejs** with  **oracle-db** module. i will explain the code as simple as possible . first i will get column information( column name , data type , length .... ) then i will get data from each column and finally append data to the specific column and get back all columns. the problem is i cant get data from the callback . thanks for your help.

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
function getRows(columnName, tableName) {
  var values = [] ;
oracledb.getConnection({user: "hr", password: "oracle"},
  function(err, connection)
  {
    if (err) {console.error(err.message);return;}
    connection.execute("select "+ columnName +"  from "+tableName+" ",  
         function(err, result)
           {
            if (err) {console.error(err.message); return;}
                      var i = 0 ;
                      if (  i < result.rows.length ) {
                        values.push({rownumber: i, value: result.rows[i][0] });
                        i++; }
                      return values;
            });
 });
return values;
}
function getColumns() {
  var Columns = [] ;
  oracledb.getConnection( { user: "hr", password: "oracle" },
  function(err, connection) {
    if (err) { console.error(err.message);  return;}
       connection.execute( "select distinct table_name, column_name, data_type, data_precision, data_length,GLOBAL_STATS, NULLABLE from all_tab_columns where owner like 'HR' order by table_name ",
        function(err, result) {
          if(err){
           console.error(err.message);
           doRelease(connection);
          return;}
             var k = 0;
             if(k < result.rows.length) {
              //get data from each column
               var values = getRows(result.rows[k][1], result.rows[k][0]);
              //get the name of the table and the column name
                  Columns.push({id: k, columnName: result.rows[k][1],tableName: result.rows[k][0], values: values });
                                        k++;

                                         }
                                              });
                                                   });
return Columns;
}
console.log(getColumns());
```

Comment: This is I think a legitimate question.   The problem in a generic way is what's called "Callback Hell" because there is a lot of asynchronous activity inside the getColumns() function.  Currently trying to figure out the same problem myself right now - will post an answer if I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your code and debug.  Also, try just using once connection (or, at least, release both connections to avoid a connection leak.).